# Invalid Identifier on LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm receiving an ORA-00904: invalid identifier at line 10 on "T.EID"

Does anybody know what I'm missing?  Am I not able to join on a calculation?

```
SELECT VEH.*,
    SUBSTR(T.PS_EMPLID, -6) AS EID, 
    T.LAST_UPDATE_DT,
    T.L1_NAME AS PRESIDENT, 
    T.L2_NAME AS Officer, 
    T.L3_NAME AS SVP, 
    T.L4_NAME AS VP, 
    T.L5_NAME AS Director
FROM V_EMP_HIER VEH
LEFT JOIN PS_HR.HR_EMPLOYEE_HIER_FACT@SBEDW_TM.WORLD T ON VEH.EMPLOYEE_NBR = T.EID
```

Comment: You cannot use EID in where clause but replace it with SUBSTR(T.PS_EMPLID, -6). T.EID is an alias of your query and it exists only during the duration of the query, not in your table with alias T.

Comment: You don't have EID column in World. Looking at your code I see you are doing a SUBSTR(T.PS_EMPLID, -6) to form EID. Use VEH.EMPLOYEE_NBR = T.SUBSTR(T.PS_EMPLID, -6). If you don't know why you can't use EID in the join let me know.

Comment: That's what I needed!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace where clause with this one. You cannot use EID in where clause but replace it with SUBSTR(T.PS_EMPLID, -6). T.EID is an alias of your query and it exists only during the duration of the query, not in your table with alias T.

```
LEFT JOIN PS_HR.HR_EMPLOYEE_HIER_FACT@SBEDW_TM.WORLD T
    ON VEH.EMPLOYEE_NBR = SUBSTR(T.PS_EMPLID, -6)
```